# Word Equation doesn't paint correctly on TOLEContainer

Tags: delphi, ole

My application uses TOLEContainer. If i embed a Word document in the OLE container and in the word document i put some equations, these equations doesn't paint properly within the application. If i open the OLE object is Word, the equation is displayed correctly.

What could be the reason? What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

if You are not use  olecontaner.CreateObjectFromFile please try this method instead of  CreateObjectFromInfo

Best regrads,
Irq Mishell